# Consulta con ELOQUENT obteniendo los nombres de mis productos - Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo tres tablas en mi BD nombre_cliente, datos_producto,stock_productos en la primera tabla tengo

### |nombre_cliente|

|id_cliente    |
|nombre        |
|id_productos  |
|id_stock      |

### |datos_porducto|

|idProducto    |
|nombre        |
|precio        |

### |stock_porducto|

|idStock       |
|cantidad      |

Cuando genero un registro en mi tabla clientes, puedo tener 1 cliente con varios productos pero mi problema es que no se como poder hacer el Join para hacer mi consulta con mi BD y que me pueda imprimir la información de mi cliente solo he logrado traer el nombre y los id de los productos.

```
public function pruebas(){

     $consulta = LogCliente::select('id_productos')->where('nombre', '=', 'Juan')->get();

     $nombre = LogCliente::select('nombre')->where('nombre', '=', 'Juan')->get();
      foreach ($nombre as $key) {
         $key->nombre;
      }


     echo $key, $consulta;


}
```

Esto me imprime

```
{"nombre":"Juan"}[{"id_producto":"284"},{"id_producto":"430"},{"id_producto":"261"}];
```

Y no se como logar que me imprima por ejemplo

```
Nombre: Juan

Productos:
Shampo, 10
Jabon,   15
Cloro,   10
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa el número que está al lado de cada producto? `Shampo, 10`

Comment: Hola @Shaz El número de productos en la tabla Stock que concuerde con el ID del producto

Comment: Pareciera que están mal formadas las relaciones en la base de datos, sin embargo, para entender un poco más: ¿En el campo `id_productos` de la tabla `nombre_cliente` se almacena un array o qué tipo de dato?

Comment: Lo almaceno como número, por ejemplo el Shampo tiene el id->1 , el jabon el id->2 y el cloro id->3 entonces en mi tabla me aparece el registro   Juan, 1 , 2   este ultimo 2 también es  un id del Stock que manejo para identificar la cantidad de producto que queda @Shaz

Comment: O sea que si Juan está asociado a 10 productos, ¿el nombre de Juan aparece 10 veces en la tabla?

Comment: Si, en mi tabla si me aparece las veces que este asociado con X productos

Comment: Ok, entonces sí hay un error (desde mi punto de vista) en el diseño de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Esto consulta en teoría debería de traerte lo que necesitás

```
$consulta = LogCliente::select('nombre_cliente.nombre')
->join('datos_porducto','nombre_cliente.id_productos','=','datos_porducto.idProducto')
->join('stock_porducto','nombre_cliente.id_stock','=','stock_porducto.idStock')
->where('nombre', '=', 'Juan')->get();
```

Te explico porque en teoría:
 - A tu entidad de Stock le hace falta el idProducto, para saber que stock corresponde a que producto, ya que de esta manera no generarás la información correcta.
Yo te recomiendo hacer esto:
Primero cambiar tu el nombre de tu entidad nombre_cliente por cliente
Para tu tabla cliente no utilices id_productos, utiliza el mismo como se llama en tu entidad producto, y adicional no utilicés plural en las entidades, algunos no lo considerar buena práctica.

- Asumiendo que lo que querés visualizar la cantidad de productos que tiene x cliente.
  lo haría de esta manera

Entidad cliente (id_cliente, nombre, id_ProdStocClie)
Entidad producto (id_producto, nombre, precio)
Entidad Prod_StocClie (id_ProdStocClie, id_producto, cantidad)

Y tu consulta debería quedarte de esta manera
// Hace tiempo que no utilizo laravel, pero recuerdo que esto no es eloquent sino querybuilder

```
$consulta = LogCliente::select('cliente.nombre', producto.nombre, prod_StocClie.cantidad)
->join('prod_StocClie','cliente.id_ProdStocClie','=','prod_StocClie.id_ProdStocClie')
->join('producto','prod_StocClie.id_producto','=','producto.id')
->where('cliente.nombre', '=', 'Juan')->get();
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: De hecho lo último que pones si estás Eloquent

Comment: @element pero igual no aprovecha las capacidades de Eloquent, así que prácticamente da lo mismo en este caso.